# Using @material-ui/lab's DataGrid component, how do you access the current active filters?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

I am integrating material-ui's data grid into one of my pages. The goal is to be able to catch the state of the filters and sorts for all the columns and save that as a link at the top of the page so users do not need to reset up the spreadsheet with their preferred values each time they load the page. The following code successfully  'pauses' the filter changes and at the point where I have the alert box I can capture all the sort orders by using

```
this.getSortModal()
```

However, I cannot find a similar function to capture the current active filter(s). How do I access the active filters in this componenet? Here is the rest basic jsx file:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { DataGrid, GridRowsProp, GridColDef } from '@material-ui/data-grid';
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";


function filterModelChanged()
{
    //Need to catch the sort and filter preferences here

    alert("you got in");
}
function Example({ initialRows, columns }) {
    //const [filters, setFilters] = useState({});
    const [rows, setRows] = useState(initialRows);
    //const filteredRows = getRows(initialRows, filters);

    return (
        <div style={{ height: 300, width: '100%' }}>
        <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} onFilterModelChange={filterModelChanged}/>
            </div>
    );
}

//
async function getData() {
    let response = await fetch("/services/reader_worklist_services/getList",
                                {credentials:"same-origin"});
    return await response.text();
}

//Need to wait till all elements are present before 'latching' onto them with the react componenet
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    getData().then(function(data) {
        const rootElement = document.getElementById('reader_worklist_container');
        const jsData = JSON.parse(data);
        //const rows = createRowData(50);
        //ReactDOM.render(<Example initialRows={rows} columns={columns} />, rootElement);
        ReactDOM.render(<Example initialRows={jsData.rows} columns={jsData.columns}  />, rootElement);
        //alert("your data is: " + data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both onFilterModelChange() and onSortModelChange() change expose the corresponding model within the params of the callback. In the case of filtering, onFilterModelChange() exposes a GridFilterModelParams model. Because of this, you could do something like the following:

```js
const onFilterModelChange = (filterObject) => {
    // Do something here
};
```

Resources:

- https://material-ui.com/api/data-grid/

Comment: Is there a way to disable the default behavior of `onFilterModelChange`, for example, I don't want it to do in row filtering (so no using filter model to hide rows). I want to make an API call and get new data based on the current filters.